# How to toggle a jquery hash url

Tags: jquery

It been a long day, I suspect that is contributing to this seemingly simple issue.

I have a burger menu that, I need to toggle the `#url` on, it needs to toggle between:

```
Open = #open
Close = #close
```

My `jquery` code looks like this:

```
        $('.menu').click(function () {
            $(this).attr("href","#close");
        });
```

and my `html` looks like this:

```
 <a href="#open" class="menu">
   <b></b>
   <b></b>
   <b></b>
   <span>Menu</span>
</a>
```

I can open the menu fine, I can close it too, however, once I have closed the menu I can't then open it again since the `href` is still showing as `#close`. So, I wondered how I can toggle it so whatever the `url`, the `href` is the opposite?

I Appreciate any help.

Comment: `window.location.hash = "open"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using location.hash to activate jquery toggle/slideToggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700276/using-location-hash-to-activate-jquery-toggle-slidetoggle)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could you expand on window.location.has and where it fits into my script, I haven't used it before.

Comment: That line would go in your `click` handler. There's also `pushState()` which allows you more control. Details are on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried that but it didn't seem to work, could you perhaps post a revised code to make sure I haven't messed up somewhere?

Comment: Use css pseudo classes to control this kind o thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check what is the `href` attribute value every time the menu is clicked and change it's value?

This should work:

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("href") == "#open") {
        $(this).attr("href", "#close");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("href", "#open");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `<a href="#open">` but alternatively `window.location.hash`.  A nice way to handle it is to use the following to do your actions:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
});
```

I make my hash string exactly like an HTTP GET string, parse the pairs manually, then shoot that off to an AJAX call.  It's a nice way to get AJAX to play with direct links and browser history.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works in your case.

```
    $('.menu').click(function(e) {
      var hash = (e.currentTarget.hash === "#close") ? '#open' : '#close'
      $(this).attr("href", hash);
    });
```