# Is a modal cookieconsent.initialise with modal href: '#modal_open' possible?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a Javascript with Osano cookieconsent.initialize. When I enter a URL at href, I come to a new page. If possible, a modal should open. Otherwise I can control a modal with '#modal_open'. Is that also possible here in the script? Thank you. Best regards

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3.1.1/build/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>

<script>
  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    "palette": {
      "popup": {
        "background": "red",
        "text": "white"
      },
      "button": {
        "background": "black)",
        "text": "white"
      }
    },
    "theme": "edgeless",
    "position": "bottom-right",
    "content": {
      "message": "This website uses cookies to improve your experience.",
      "dismiss": "OK",
      "link": "Learn more",
      "href": "#modal_open"
    }
  });
</script>


  <div id="modal_open" class="modalDialog">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="modal_close">X</a>
      <div class="load"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".load" ).load( "sites/site.html" );
  </script>
```

Comment: Read this, it's similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275957/how-to-toggle-a-jquery-hash-url

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me :(